# DHTMLX SCHEDULER

Tags: scheduler, dhtmlx

[enter image description here][1] I want to add Time period section to fully custom light box.

```
    [<form id='form1'>
      <span class="label">Text</span><input id="Text1" name="text" type="text"/><br />
      <span class="label">From</span><input id="start_date" name="start_date"  type="text"/>
      <span class="label">to</span><input id="end_date" name="end_date" type="text"/><br />
      <span class="label">Room_id</span><input id="Text4" name="room_id" type="text"/>
      <span class="label">User Id</span><input id="Text5" name="user_id" type="text"/>
       <input type="text" id="patient_name" name="patient_name"/>
       <input type="text" id="patient_dob" name="patient_dob"/>
      <input id="Hidden1" name="id" type="hidden"/>
   </form>][1]
```

[1]: SEE this Image https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3spf.png

Comment: You're probably going to need to add a lot more details than this. This is pretty vague.

Comment: Then how to set time /date in custom lightbox ?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be very difficult

1. you need to find a date-time picker component that works for you
   (datepicker embedded into dhtmlxScheduler lacks time-picker
   functionality)
2. when user opens lightbox - you initialize datepickers in form inputs and assign event.start_date/end_date into them
3. when user saves lightbox - you get values from datepickers and update event.start_date/end_date with those values.

Here is a demo - http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/snippet/5e45f342

I used this example https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/samples/02_customization/16_custom_form.html and flatpickr datepicker https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr/ for it.